# Issue in plotting a line chart of GHG emissions of a Nation over time

Tags: r, dataframe, graphics

This is the tibble of data which I'm working with:

Global_Carbon_Data

A tibble: 488 x 3

|  | Nation | Year | GHG Emissions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | chr | dbl | dbl |
| 1 | Canada | 1959 | 50.3 |
| 2 | Canada | 1960 | 52.6 |
| 3 | Canada | 1961 | 52.9 |
| 4 | Canada | 1962 | 56.5 |
| 5 | Canada | 1963 | 57.6 |
| 6 | Canada | 1964 | 64.8 |
| 7 | Canada | 1965 | 68.8 |
| 8 | Canada | 1966 | 70.7 |
| 9 | Cananda | 1967 | 76.9 |
| 10 | Canada | 1968 | 82.8 |

With more rows going all the way to 2019.

With G7 nations + China.

I'm running:

```
ggplot(Global_Carbon_Data, mapping = aes(Year, 'ghg emmision')) +
 geom_point(size = 4, colour = "white") +
 geom_point(aes(colour=Nation))
```

To receive a single line of points labelled  GHG Emissions.

[image: Output Table]

The Nations have been clearly defined and found by R. More evidently it even draws a different dots for each nation as I get USA on top when I try to make a line graph using the tibble and the same variables.

[image: Output Graph for Line Chart]

Why isn't R recognising and plotting the numerical values by GHG emissions.

I've also attached my excel sheet for reference.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkorxCoXh2CnmfshzSj7p8Nfs6twAw?e=S2kzVm

Thanks in advance for any help.

Using the code which Marco Sandri suggested gives me:

[image: Using the code which Marco Sandri suggested gives me:]

I'm also going to try to replace the space with an underscore and correct the spelling of emissions while I'm at it.

That gave an output of:

[image]

Which works.

Comment: I tried before it isn't case sensitive and gives the same output except the legend makes the GHG capital aswell.

Comment: That isn't working either. Replacing space with an underscore did though so I'm just going to do that and use title().

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Please, could you share the output of `dput(head(Global_Carbon_Data))` ? I would like to better understand your problem.

Comment: The output for that was:

structure(list(Nation = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada"), Year = c(1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964
), GHG_Emissions = c(50.34971457, 52.59720929, 52.94778756, 56.49311441, 
57.56298465, 64.84108441)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: The name of the variable is `GHG_Emissions` and not `GHG Emissions` as from your table in the post (or `ghg emmision` ). So you should use `ggplot(Global_Carbon_Data, mapping = aes(Year, GHG_Emissions))`. This solution works on my R machine.

Comment: Yup that works thank you very much.